# Grouped data in python with pandas and

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pivot-table, data-analysis

I use python, pandas, numpy.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print df.head(7)
```

I have DataFrame:

```
name  day  sum
A      D1    6 
B      D1    7 
B      D3    8 
A      D10   3 
A      D2    4 
C      D2    6 
A      D1    9
```

I need:

```
name   D1    D2      D3     ... D10
A      =6+9  =6+9+4  =6+9+4    =6+9+4+...+3
B      =7    =7      =7+8      =7+8+...+ 
C      =0    =0+6    =0+6        =6+...
```

I need to get the following table with a cumulative total:

```
name   D1    D2     D3    ... D10
A      15    19     19       ....
B      7     7      15      
C      0     6      6
```

Please tell me how I can do it?
Thank you!

p.s. I use function **pivot_table**, (but the result is not cumulative total):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.pivot_table(df, values='sum', index=['name'], columns=['day'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use df.cumsum(axis=1)

```
pivotedDf = pd.pivot_table(df, values='sum', index=['name'], columns=['day'], aggfunc=np.sum)
pivotedDf = pivotedDf[['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D10']]  # manually sort columns
pivotedDf.cumsum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pivot`ing with `sum`, followed by `fillna`, actually *does* exactly what you specified in the question:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
  name  day  sum
0    A   D1    6
1    B   D1    7
2    B   D3    8
3    A  D10    3
4    A   D2    4
5    C   D2    6
6    A   D1    9

In [19]: pd.pivot_table(df, values='sum', index=['name'], columns=    ['day'], aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)
Out[19]: 
day     D1  D10   D2   D3
name                     
A     15.0  3.0  4.0  0.0
B      7.0  0.0  0.0  8.0
C      0.0  0.0  6.0  0.0
```

For example, *15.0 = 6 + 9*, exactly as you specified it should be.